# Mercurial: Move a collection of files to an unrelated repository

Tags: mercurial

I have a bunch of files, its actually a c# project and the files related to it, the whole hg repository is a solution with many projects.
I need to move those (with history) to another *existing* repository .

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: My advice is: don't. Merging history of unrelated projects extremely hard to do right: it means replaying the history of one project inside the other. The various hacks people are proposing won't do this and will result in a confusing history. Here's an example of how I recently handled this in the Mercurial project itself: http://www.selenic.com/hg/rev/cfccd3bee7b3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say, you have A and B repositories. Your goal is to extract an 'a' folder in A and merge it with B to make B_with_a, while preserving histories.

1) Extract 'a' in A and make Aa. You can do this with hg convert:

`~$ hg convert A Aa --filemap list.txt`

where list.txt is

`include a`

2) Pull Aa to B - to make B_with_a_yet_merged. You have to use -f since they are not related.

`~/B$ hg pull ./../Aa -f`

3) Merge two branches in B_with_a_yet_merged to make B_with_a

`~/B$ hg merge (with the last rev in Aa)`

PS.
Don't forget to backup A and B beforehand! When I first did this, I messed up repositories three times.

Comment: I recently used [Git recipe](https://github.com/odoomrp/odoomrp-wip/wiki/Migration-to-OCA) to transpile one folder into another repo with history, and it has been a great exercise. I was wondering if Mercurial had this kind of things, and not only it has, but it's easier (as always). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After a poke around hg commands I found bundle, seemed to have made the trick. More details soon

Update: tried this and didnt work. It brought the files when I unbundled it, and I was able to merge, but for some reason the graph was off.
I just thought I d post for completeness

Comment: Bundle is equivalent to push/pull.